# Selecting first thumb photo for albums

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble selecting first photo (`thumb_filename`) and date added (`date_added`) on every unique article. Every unique article is a gallery for itself.

I am beginner in MySQL, so hope someone could help.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photographs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `full_filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `article_id` (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;
```

I know to use `SELECT thumb_filename, date_added FROM photographs` and than to filter this out using PHP. I don't know how to set condition for unique `article_id`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested of course, but this may do the job for you. This isn't the only way to do it, but it is a straightforward way. It pulls photograph `id`s for the earliest `date_added` of each `article_id` and then uses those to retrieve the filename.

```
SELECT 
  thumb_filename,
  date_added
FROM photographs
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM photographs GROUP BY article_id HAVING MIN(date_added))
```

Comment: You have one `select` more, otherwise that is solution. Thanks.